# how can I delimit in ruby 'split' with multiple delimiters?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following code.  My intend is to be able to parse the last full sentence in a string of sentences:

```
string = "something for nothing.  'nothing for free.'"
string.split(/!|\.|\.'|\?/)
=> ["something for nothing", "  'nothing for free", "'"]
```

I would like to be able to do `array.last` and get the last sentence, whether it ends in '!', '?', '.', or the end of a quote like, ." or .'

But when I try to include a combination, as above, it doesn't treat the `.'` part as a single delimiter.

Comment: You should provide more examples to clarify your question.

Comment: `string.split(/!|\.|\.'|\?/)` will cause the output to delete the delimiters such as `.` `?` etc ( eg `'nothing for free"` here the *sentence* doesn't end with `.'` ). Am not sure if this is what you intend to obtain

Comment: I want it to get the last sentence, and the sentence could end either with a `.'` or it could be a regular sentence, like `.`

Comment: How about `Mr.` or `Jr.` in a sentence or some numbers in a sentence like `5.25`

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, there are two spaces between the sentences. So just split on them, instead of using a regex, which is not needed here at all.

```
puts string.split("  ").last #=> 'nothing for free.'
```

If punctuation is guaranteed, then you can use the rex

```
puts string.split(/(?<=[.?!]("|'|))\s+/).last
```

The regex `/(?<=[.?!]("|'|\s))\s+/` uses lookbehind and splits on the space after `.` or `?` or `!` + `"` or `'` or space.

Comment: sometimes it is two spaces, some times it is one space.

Comment: @Angela do sentences always start with `'`?

Comment: No, they don't.  Mostly they don't.

Comment: @Angela at least, are you sure that sentences end with a full-stop?

Comment: Yes, all sentences must end in a full-stop punctuation: `.` , `!`, `?`, `."`, `?"`, `.'`

Comment: Thanks let me try that

Comment: @Angela great. If it worked, do mark it as answer by clicking the tick mark. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "something for nothing.  'nothing for free.'. Something for free? '...Everything for FREE!!!!!!...' "

string.split(/\b?\.\s|\?\s|\!\s/)
```

> => ["something for nothing", "    'nothing for free.'", "Something for free", "'...Everything for FREE!!!!!!...' "]